# htaccess rewrite returns 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want it so that if the user types **webaddress.com/artist/P1/P2/** it will make it use **/artist/index.php?artist=P1&am=P2**

P1 would be an artist name, so it could contain both letters and numbers.
P2 would be a number, so just numbers.

I want it so that P1 would be esssential, whereas P2 isn't because right now it just returns 404 not found on that address. Current code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artist/([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ /artist/index.php?artist=$1&am=$2 [L]
```

Comment: have you checked what's actually returning the 404? It could either be because there isn't a `/artist/index.php` on your script... or maybe that script is actually running, but issuing its own 404 because the artist/am parameters are incorrect.

Comment: The script exists, and it doesn't seem to be directing me anywhere as it loads right away. Could you tell me if there's anything wrong with the code I provided by any chance?

Comment: well, stuff a `die('Yoohoo!')` or something at the top of the index.php script. If you get that, then your rewrite is at least pointing at the right script, and you should check `var_dump($_GET)` to see if your parameters are coming through ok. If you DON'T get the yoohoo output, then something's wrong with the rewrite

Comment: If I go directly to the script and use it via /artist/index.php then it works fine with all the parameters included. It's just via this rewrite it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: where exactly do you have this rewrite rule? Depending on if it's in a vhost or directory block, you MAY need to put in th eleading `/`, e.g. `^/artist/...`

Comment: I have it in /public_html/ whereas the script is in /public_html/artist/

Comment: yes, but is it in a .htaccess file, or in httpd.conf? If it's in the conf, is it inside `<VirtualHost>`, or `<Directory>`?

Comment: It's in a .htaccess file.

Comment: What does your error log say about the 404?

Comment: It isn't saying anything about the 404 for some reason, just my past errors.

It works using: RewriteRule ^artist/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ artist/index.php?artist=$1&am=$2 [R]

but only if I include the second parameter in it, otherwise it will just 404.

Answer (score 0):

/artist/index.php implies there is a root directory on the server call /artist/. I somehow doubt this (and it it does exist, it shouldnt).

Remove the leading / before artist, and see if that works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artist/([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ artist/index.php?artist=$1&am=$2 [L]
```